# How to enable syntax highlighting for template variables in VS 2022

Tags: syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-2022

I am not able to find a setting where I can enable syntax highlighting for template variables within a script - template.
In VS 2019 it works.

In the case below I would like to see email and password highlighted.

````
<script id="login-template" type="text/template">

        <section class="section is-relative mx-auto">
            <div class="container mx-auto">
                <h1 class="is-size-1">Login</h1>
                <div class="columns is-multiline">
                    <div class="column is-6 is-4-desktop mb-5 mr-auto">
                        <div>
                            <div class="mx-auto py-5 has-text-centered">
                                <form id="form" action="#" data-bitwarden-watching="1">
                                    <span class="has-text-grey-dark">Sign In</span>
                                    <h3 class="mb-5 is-size-4 has-text-weight-bold">Login to timetables.io</h3>
                                    <div class="field">
                                        <div class="control">
                                            <input id="email" class="input" type="text" value="{{ **email** }}" placeholder="E-mail address">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="field">
                                        <div class="control">
                                            <input id="password" class="input" type="email" value="{{ **password** }}" placeholder="Password">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button class="button is-primary mb-4" on-click="['login']">Login</button>
                                    <button class="button is-secondary mb-4 is-outlined" on-click="['logout']">Login</button>
                                    <a class="mb-5 is-inline-block" href="#"><small>Forgot password?</small></a>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

</script>
```
````